# How to get cartesian product of OrdinalEncoder in Scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Code:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing


data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
feature_cols = ['country', 'city', 'pay_type']
X = data[feature_cols]
y = data.label
oe = preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()
X = oe.fit_transform(X)
print(oe.categories_)
for element in itertools.product(oe.categories_):
    print(element)
```

And Output:

```
[array(['Saudi Arabia'], dtype=object), array(['Dammam', 'Jeddah', 'Madinah', 'Makkah', 'Riyadh', 'Taif'],
      dtype=object), array(['COD', 'PREPAID'], dtype=object)]
(array(['Saudi Arabia'], dtype=object),)
(array(['Dammam', 'Jeddah', 'Madinah', 'Makkah', 'Riyadh', 'Taif'],
      dtype=object),)
(array(['COD', 'PREPAID'], dtype=object),)
```

From the output, we have 3 features and the value range is:

```
Country: 'Saudi Arabia'
City: 'Dammam', 'Jeddah', 'Madinah', 'Makkah', 'Riyadh', 'Taif'
Pay type: 'COD', 'PREPAID'
```

I want to get the cartesian product of all feature values, that is to say:

```
('Saudi Arabia', 'Dammam', 'COD')
('Saudi Arabia', 'Dammam', 'PREPAID')
('Saudi Arabia', 'Jeddah', 'COD')
...
```

And I tried to `itertools.product`, but only output 3 element instead of cartesian product.

Could anyone please give me some hints about getting cartesian product of those feature values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You'll need to do something like:

```
...
for element in itertools.product(*oe.categories_):
    print(element)
```

Basically you have to unpack the `oe.categories_` so that it can be seen as separate iterables for `itertools.product`.